# Ejabberd On SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, centos, odbc, ejabberd

I'm using Ejabberd 15.03 on CentOs and i want to connect it via SQL Server on 
Windows Server.

I installed the database from [a sample SQL Server 2012 script](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/blob/master/sql/mssql2012.sql)

In ejabberd.yml i added this

```
> host_config:   "example.com":
>     odbc_type: odbc
>     odbc_server: "ip adress"
>     odbc_port: 1433 # the default
>     odbc_database: "ejjaberd"
>     odbc_username: "username"
>     odbc_password: "password"
```

I'm getting this error when starting ejabberd

> /opt/ejabberd-15.03/lib/odbc-2.10.19/priv/bin/odbcserver: error while
>   loading shared libraries: libodbc.so.1: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory

Let me precise that direct connection using tsql works perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, MSSQL is probably not working anymore as we have had no need for MSSQL support (and do not even have access to an instance of MSSQL server). Until someone step in to help with MSSQL support, I do not think it can tested against MSSQL.